# A wireless gaming headset that works for linux, windows, macosx, andriod, and ios under 200 usd

Tags: linux, smartphones, windows, headset, osx

**The problem in general**

So I'm on the search for a new gaming headset. I go through headsets like crazy due to the fact that I constantly drop things. Dropped item with wire plugged in = damaged wire. So I finally got off my high horse and decided to buy a wireless headset. The real question? How to I get one that works across my countless devices?

**Requirements:**

- Works with the following OS:

  - Lunbuntu 18.04
  - windows 10 home
  - android nougat
  - ios 12.1.4
  - mac osx 10.14
- Comfortable for long play sessions
- Fairly low latency

**Preferred but not required:**

- surround sound that works on linux, macosx, and windows.

**Things I don't really care about:**

- Fancy control stuff like razer synapse as long as the sound quality and microphone are fairly good without it.
- The ever ensuing terminal headache as long as there are instructions to show me how to do it without breaking something.
- Connecting to multiple devices at once

**Budget:**

- 200 usd

Comment: If the core issue is that the wire gets ruined often, have you considered headsets with replaceable wires? Even some gaming headsets with a mic have a replaceable cable. The headset end is usually a standard 2.5mm or 3.5mm jack.

Comment: Also a couple tips to point you in the right direction: 1. A 'plug & play' USB Audio headset should be supported by every platform without needing any drivers. 2. Anything with surround sound must either use a special driver (not plug & play) or have a built-in processor to upmix stereo into surround. Avoid this feature if you want hassle-free cross-platform support. 3. You can get 3.5mm -> Bluetooth transmitters that would pair with any bluetooth headset. Although these usually don't support a mic, your headphones would still work with any 3.5mm output.

Comment: Seconding the "headsets usually require surround sound drivers." Besides that though, you've got a massive, massive range of headphones; AFAIK most Bluetooth headphones/headsets will be perfectly happy cross-platform. I'm assuming you'd prefer close-backed, over-ear? Any interest in noise-cancelling?

Comment: @JMY1000 don’t most Bluetooth headsets have extremely high latency? Also to answer your question closed back over ear noise canceling. I cap at 200ms total.

Comment: @MageintheBarrel It depends on several factors, including hardware (both of the headphones and the device), codec, OS, and drivers. However, I really don't see what your other options are given the wide range of OSs you want. Sure, you could get something with a proprietary low-latency dongle and carry around whatever adapters you need to use it with a phone, but do you *really* want to go through all the pain and hassle of that, especially on a locked-down platform like iOS? (cont.)

Comment: If you're really that concerned about latency, get a wired headset with a detachable cable. Or, if you want flexibility, get a wireless headset with an optional detachable cable. Frankly though, in my experience (even with non-gaming-oriented headphones), latency just hasn't been a big issue.